# How to export error-handling to a function in C using <errno.h>

Tags: c, refactoring, exit, errno, strerror

I am checking if user enters the correct number and type of cmd arguments when calling main.

I thought it would be a great idea to write a function, which prints out some text, so I can reuse it when checking for `NULL` pointers. I included `<errno.h>`.

```
void errcall()
{
  perror("Error printed by perror()");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Then I wrote a function to check if arguments are right and sufficient.

```
void err_cmd_handle(int argc_input)
{
  if(argc_input==1 || argc_input>2)
    errcall(); 
}
```

When I call this in main, giving `int argc` as an argument to `err_cmd_handle()`, then I get a success, even when I did not give *any* arguments besides starting the program. Why does the condition fail to check correctly?

```
int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
  err_cmd_handle(argc);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think `errno` might have a useful value when you call `errcall`?

Comment: Please provide a complete example.  Your explanation of what you're doing in `main()` and your "I think it has something to do with my functions being implicit or my variables being in the wrong scope" make what you're actually doing very unclear.

Comment: @rici I suppose it is set to a value when user types cmd arguments are passed, as far as I know.

Comment: If you are getting warnings about implicit functions or anything else - fix them _before_ asking about the problem.  Or if you think those warnings are relevant include them in the question!

Comment: So this whole error-handling stuff in errno.h is not even useful for checking pointers? I mean like if files are opened?

Comment: I _am_ helping you, by trying to understand your question.  However I deleted my comment because I saw the relevance of `errcall()` - it is not obvious your question kind of gets to the important stuff last.  However bee clear _errno_ is irrelevant to your task, but the question of why it returns success remains valid.

Comment: Ah, whatever I will just delete the post, maybe if I put 50 hours into researching this topic I will understand it. All this is good for is loosing points and looking a dork.

Comment: If for example a standard library function returns an error state (as documented) and it is _documented_ that it sets `errno`, then it is valid to check `errno`.  It is not a general purpose error handling support - it is for reporting errors from the standard library.

Comment: @BalázsBörcsök : Don't do that - have patience, answer the comments by improving the question - you are being over sensitive.  Ultimately your question is not about errno, it is about why the `if(argc_input==1 || argc_input>2)` apparently fails.   Your question cannot be answered without further information and investigation because it is implausible and is more likely an observation error.

Comment: So `errno` is set after each function call?

Comment: No - after function calls that explicitly state they set it in their documentation - not all function calls.  It is off-topic however - you did not ask about errno - just talked about it - it may have been better had you not done so and simplified the question to just exit-success, exit-error and asked separately about validation of command line arguments.

Comment: It seems like for me that you have perfectly understood what was my problem. It is hard to ask the right question if I am tapping in the dark.

Comment: It is an error of observation - I will post an answer now I have figured it out - too long for a comment.  You should have included the _output_ of your program - it would then be very obvious what was happening.

Comment: You did not "get a success", rather you got an error and printed "success".  Simple as that.  In future post all of: input, actual output, expected output, code (complete not fragments) and if there are build issues, the build log.  Consider that a check list for a good question and you will get far fewer problems in future.  Even rookie questions can get up-votes just for being well formed.  Do persevere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take your complete code with required headers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void errcall()
{
  perror("Error printed by perror()");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
void err_cmd_handle(int argc_input)
{
  if(argc_input==1 || argc_input>2)errcall(); 
}

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    err_cmd_handle(argc);
    return 0;
}
```

and then run it with no arguments, the output is:

```
Error printed by perror(): Success
```

Clearly the validation has worked because `errcall()` has been called.  The text "Success" is simply because the value of `errno` is zero - because nothing has set it.

Your original code before you changed the question had:

```
if(argc_input==1 || argc_input>2)errcall();
  else exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

So when you stated:

> then I get a success, even when I did not give any arguments besides
>   starting the program

It was reasonable to assume that it was terminating via `exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);` - that is clearly not the case.  It was also you I originally assumed that `errno` had nothing to do with the question because it seemed that `errcall()` cannot have been called if it returned `EXIT_SUCCESS`.  Hopefully you see why your question caused so much confusion and comment?

Comment: Note also that function calls can modify `errno`.  Per [**7.5 Errors &lt;errno.h>**, p3](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.5p3): "The value of `errno` may be set to nonzero by a library function call whether or not there is an error, provided the use of `errno` is not documented in the description of the function in this International Standard."  I'm also pretty certain I've seen standard functions that do document their use of `errno` munging its value when there has been no error, so the value of `errno` is only truly useful immediately after a function has failed.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I think your comment is misplaced.  It has no relevance to this answer.  Perhaps you were addressing comments posted to the question itself.  Earlier in that conversation, I clearly stated that errno only indicates an error when the function that sets it returns the error state.

Comment: @BalázsBörcsök consider this, _you_ have decided that `argc_input==1 || argc_input>2` is an error condition, `perrno()` does not magically know to print an error, it simply renders specific _known_ standard values of _errno_ as text. You could set _errno_ yourself, but it was really intended for system errors rather than application level errors, where you could output more helpful and relevant information such as a command line help/usage guide

Answer (score 1):

Errno hasn't been set.

```
void errcall()
{
  printf("Value of errno: %d\n", errno);
  printf("Error: %s\n",strerror(errno));
  perror("Error printed by perror()");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    if(argc!=2) 
    {
       errno=EINVAL;
       errcall();
    }

    return 0;
}
```